# How to create desktop shortcut to bash program running java

Tags: bash, java, shortcuts

I've downloaded the free and open-source image analysis software "Icy" (http://icy.bioimageanalysis.org/), and I can launch it by making the "icy.sh" file executable and double-clicking on it.

*However* if I create a shortcut to this file, I can't launch it, **except** if the shortcut is in the original folder.
Here is a clue, that this is possibly due to the fact that "Java programs need to be started from within the directory in which their files exist.": https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher

But I have no idea of how it actually works and how to solve that.
If you have any idea that would be great :-)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you open that icy.sh file, you can see

```
    java -jar updater.jar
```

So you can just modify (leafpad, gedit or any other text editor)your icy.desktop file to:

```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=ICY
   Exec=java -jar '/your/path/to/file/updater.jar' 
   Icon=your/path/to/icon
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
```

With icy.sh set as executable and with shortcut created as:

```
   Exec=/your/path/to/file/icy.sh
```

it didnt work, like in your case... this is workaround I would use

Comment: YES! I actually did that before checking your answer and it works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Icy
Exec=/bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/script/directory&&./icy.sh"
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

- Copy it into an empty file, save it as `icy.desktop`
- Replace `/path/to/script/directory` by the actual path to the script's directory
- Make it executable

#### Explanation

Desktop files (with the extension .desktop) can be used to perform all kinds of applications or tasks. To make it run shell commands, the format is:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "<command>"
```

The `<command>` in this case is:

```
cd /path/to/script/directory&&./icy.sh
```

In detail:

```
cd /path/to/script/directory
```

to `cd` to the script's directory, and subsequently:

```
./icy.sh
```

to run `icy.sh` from its own directory

#### Give the .desktop file an(other) icon:

The example file is a very basic one:

[image]

If you'd like the file to have another icon than the generic one, add a line (e.g.):

```
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
```

[image]

More on `.desktop` files and their required/optional entries [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

Comment: Very nice answer, it made my day :-) !

Answer (score 0):

You can open the "shortcut" as a plain text using any text editor. When opened, you must change the path of the file. Probably now it's a relative path, so make it absolute to look like "./home/user/pathtofile/file.sh"